# Jenkins : Global Tool Configuration - setup differs based on agent

Tags: jenkins

The Global Tool Configuration page in jenkins allows me to save tools and locations, e.g.   MSBuild installations on nodes. What is the recommanded setup to allow these tools to be installed at different locations on each of my nodes ?
To be more explicit is there a way to override the default location defined on jenkins server side for one of my agents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that in each node, and menu "Node Properties" there is an option "Tool Locations" that allows me to override the tools default location.